Loop Through Workbook and Place Worksheet Names in Columns without Skipping Rows
I have this code and don't understand the row counter entry. I thought it was supposed to populate only the empty cells. In the loop of the 1st If statement, it should populate the column starting with cell I1. In the loop of the 2nd If statement, it should populate the column starting with cell K1.
    Dim rowCounter As Integer

    Set datasheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    ' Clear previous entries in columns I and K
    datasheet. Range("I:I, K:K").ClearContents

    ' Loop through all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        If Right$(ws.Name, 3) = "MAP" Then
            ' Write the sheet name to column K of the "Data" sheet
            datasheet. Cells(rowCounter, "K").Value = ws.Name
        End If

        ' Check if any cell in column I contains a hyphen
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 And Right$(ws.Name, 3) <> "MAP" Then
            ' Write the sheet name to column I of the "Data" sheet
            While Not dataSheet.Cells(rowCounter, "I").Value = "" 'ws.Name
                rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            Wend
            datasheet. Cells(rowCounter, "I").Value = ws.Name
        End If

        'Check if the sheet name is in the list to hide
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, sheetNamesToHide, 0)) Then
            'Sheet names not found in the list, so not hidden
        Else
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If

    Next ws

I need to fill the Data list starting in cell I1, and K1. The code is skipping the first 20 lines, and then adding 3-4 entries, and skipping ten more cells and adds a few more.

It does exactly what it's been written like, rowCounter = rowCounter + 1 is placed int he loop that goes through each worksheet, causing the skipping and inconsistency.

You have put your counter in the wrong place and it was skipping rows looping thru sheet names which were not being populated.  I think you meant to have something like this instead:
Sub FillData()

    Dim rowCounterI As Integer
    Dim rowCounterK As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNamesToHide As Variant

    ' Initialize row counters
    rowCounterI = 1
    rowCounterK = 1

    ' Set the data sheet
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    ' Clear previous entries in columns I and K
    dataSheet.Range("I:I, K:K").ClearContents

    ' Loop through all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        ' Check if the sheet name contains a hyphen but is not a "MAP" sheet
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 And Right$(ws.Name, 3) <> "MAP" Then
            ' Write the sheet name to column I
            dataSheet.Cells(rowCounterI, "I").Value = ws.Name
            rowCounterI = rowCounterI + 1
        End If

        ' Check if the sheet name ends with "MAP"
        If Right$(ws.Name, 3) = "MAP" Then
            ' Write the sheet name to column K
            dataSheet.Cells(rowCounterK, "K").Value = ws.Name
            rowCounterK = rowCounterK + 1
        End If
        
        ' Check if the sheet name should be hidden
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, sheetNamesToHide, 0)) Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub


That worked Michal, thank you, and thanks for the input Basic. But, if I could bother you with one more problem. I need to sort the two ranges, I have the next column over with formulas to produce 1-6 on the entries of the I and K ranges, so I need to sort on those numbers. Here's the code I have that is saying the range is nothing for some reason.
I apparently have to post another question to get the sorting sorted out. I swear.

List and Hide Worksheets

Sub ListAndHide()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Dim NAMES_OF_SHEETS_TO_HIDE As Variant:
    NAMES_OF_SHEETS_TO_HIDE = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3-MAP")
    Dim SRC_SHEET_NAME_PATERNS() As Variant:
    SRC_SHEET_NAME_PATERNS = VBA.Array("*MAP", "*-*")
    Const TGT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Data"
    Dim TGT_SHEET_COLUMNS() As Variant:
    TGT_SHEET_COLUMNS = VBA.Array("K", "I")
    ' Note: 'SRC_SHEET_NAME_PATERNS' must have the same number of elements
    '       as 'TGT_SHEET_COLUMNS'.
    
    ' Reference the workbook (right after the constants).

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the target sheet, the one being written to.

    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TGT_SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Declare a counter variable to be used to loop through the elements
    ' of the arrays holding the source sheet patterns, the target sheet columns,
    ' and the target current rows, all at the same time.
    
    Dim u As Long
    
    ' Clear the contents of the target columns.
    
    Dim Upper As Long: Upper = UBound(SRC_SHEET_NAME_PATERNS)
    
    For u = 0 To Upper
        tws.Columns(TGT_SHEET_COLUMNS(u)).ClearContents
    Next u
        
    ' Define an array of the same size as the size of the source sheet patterns
    ' or the target sheet columns. Each element will hold the current
    ' (target) row in each target column.
        
    Dim tRows() As Long: ReDim tRows(0 To Upper)
        
    ' Loop through the sheets and apply the required logic...
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim sws As Worksheet, SheetNameIndex As Variant, dRow As Long
    Dim sSheetName As String, IsPatternMatched As Boolean
    
    ' Loop.
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Set.
        sSheetName = sws.Name
        IsPatternMatched = False ' reset
        ' If the sheet name matches a pattern, write it to the target sheet.
        For u = 0 To Upper
            ' Note: This comparison is case-sensitive i.e. 'A <> a'.
            If sSheetName Like SRC_SHEET_NAME_PATERNS(u) Then ' match
                tRows(u) = tRows(u) + 1
                tws.Cells(tRows(u), TGT_SHEET_COLUMNS(u)).Value = sSheetName
                IsPatternMatched = True
                Exit For
            'Else ' not a match; do nothing
            End If
        Next u
        ' Note: Think of the previous loop as if it were the 'Case' clauses
        '       of a 'Select Case' statement while the following 'If' statement
        '       as the 'Case Else' clause.
        ' In case you want to do something when the sheet name
        ' doesn't match any patterns.
        If Not IsPatternMatched Then
            Debug.Print "Sheet """ & sSheetName _
                & """ matches none of the patterns (""" _
                & Join(SRC_SHEET_NAME_PATERNS, """, """) & """)."
        End If
        ' Check if the sheet name is in the list of sheets to hide.
        ' Note: This happens whether a pattern was matched or not.
        ' Note: This search ('Match') is case-insensitive i.e. 'A = a'
        SheetNameIndex = Application.Match( _
            sSheetName, NAMES_OF_SHEETS_TO_HIDE, 0)
        If IsNumeric(SheetNameIndex) Then
            Debug.Print "Hiding sheet """ & sSheetName & """."
            sws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        'Else ' sheet name not found in the list
            ' Either do nothing...
            ' ... or unhide:
            'sws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
        
    Next sws
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Sheets listed and hidden.", vbInformation

End Sub

Results in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)
Sheet "Data" matches none of the patterns ("*MAP", "*-*").
Sheet "Sheet2" matches none of the patterns ("*MAP", "*-*").
Hiding sheet "Sheet2".
Hiding sheet "Sheet3-MAP".

